# how to find the median of 7 numbers? (without any using of Math Methods)

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement, median

How to find the median of 7 or 9 numbers? (without any using of Math Methods)

I have already found one way but it's too long but I can't find any other way to solve it. (I swapped the numbers with each other and forced one value to be the median)

This is what i have done. I dont allowed to use API Math Methods and Array Methods.

```
public class Statistik {
        public static double median7(double a, double b, double c, double d, double e, double f, double g) {
        double h;
        if (a < b) {
            h = a;
            a = b;
            b = h;
        }
        if (a < c) {
            h = a;
            a = c;
            c = h;
        }
        if (a < d) {
            h = a;
            a = d;
            d = h;
        }
        if (a > e) {
            h = a;
            a = e;
            e = h;
            if (a < b) {
                h = a;
                a = b;
                b = h;
            }
            if (a < c) {
                h = a;
                a = c;
                c = h;
            }
            if (a < d) {
                h = a;
                a = d;
                d = h;
            }
        }
        if (a > f) {
            h = a;
            a = f;
            f = h;
            if (a < b) {
                h = a;
                a = b;
                b = h;
            }
            if (a < c) {
                h = a;
                a = c;
                c = h;
            }
            if (a < d) {
                h = a;
                a = d;
                d = h;
            }
        }
        if (a > g) {
            h = a;
            a = g;
            g = h;
            if (a < b) {
                h = a;
                a = b;
                b = h;
            }
            if (a < c) {
                h = a;
                a = c;
                c = h;
            }
            if (a < d) {
                h = a;
                a = d;
                d = h;
            }
        }
        double median7 = a;
        return median7;// TODO
    }
```

}

Comment: What do you mean? How do I find the middle number? For collections with an uneven number of elements:
`index = numbers.length()/2+1; mean = numbers.get(index);`? Is that what you are asking? Please post what you have tried, and explain what the problem is.

Comment: Java != JavaScript

Comment: i added what i've done.

Answer (score 0):

First, you cannot find the median of one single number. So I'm taking it as finding the median of 7 and 9. To do that, just follow this code:

```
console.log((7 + 9) / 2);
```

Or, if you want to find the median of a list, then use this code:

```
function sortNumber(a,b) {
  return a - b;
}
let numbersList = []; // plug in numbers
numbersList.sort(sortNumber);
let a = numbersList.length
let b = (a + 1) / 2
console.log(numbersList[b - 1]);
```

Comment: By the way, this code is in JavaScript. Which is not the same as Java.

Comment: by "median of 7", i mean 7 numbers. My english is not good, I'm sorry

Comment: Oh, okay, just plug in seven numbers in the list `numbersList`.